# I can't "unmaximize" my window

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server

I've got a windows app (I don't think it matters which one, but in case you're wondering, it's SQL Server Profiler) that I can't put back into "windowed" mode.  I can maximize or minimize it, either by right-clicking on the task bar and selecting maximize...or if the window is already maximized, I can click the minimize button to minimize it...

The problem is when I click the middle button...the one that toggles between maximized and "windowed" mode, the windowed mode just makes it disappear.  The program is still running fine, and I can bring it back up (maximized) by selecting it in the task bar.  It doesn't seem to be hanging out on any of the edges of the screen...far as I can tell, it's just not there.  And, of course, the app is "smart" enough to remember its status, so restarting the app doesn't help.

Has anyone seen this?  Know how to fix it?

Comment: What happens when (with that window in focus) you hit Alt-Space and then the letter R?

Comment: @Michael: If I do this while it's maximized, it just disappears.  Again, it's still in the taskbar, but no window is visible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the option of right clicking the program on the task bar, and selecting "Move". If so, do not move the mouse, just use the arrow keys on the keyboard (they will move the program). Try a direction, if you don't see the window move it the same distance in the opposite direction (otherwise you might be moving it further off-screen).

Comment: Cha-ching!  That did it!  Not sure how it managed to get offscreen (and shrunk down to a bizarrely small state) like this, but this did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 sounds like the sort of thing that can happen when you have a multi-monitor setup and then change this, or even change the resolution in an unusual way so that an absolute position ends up off screen

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. So I started Task Manager, located the program on the Applications tab, right-clicked and selected Maximize. At that point you can click the header and drag the window wherever you want.